# Why do some HTML elements allow "crossover"?

Tags: html

Why is it that if I do:

```
<div> aaaaaaaa <b></div>
<div> bbbbbbbb </div>
<div> </b> ccccccccc </div>
```

...the content "bbbbbbbb" is in bold? Then why can't I do the same with another tag such as <span> instead of <b>? Is the bold case just the browser trying to fix it or is it actually valid?

I am attemping to hide some text content that could span several <div> tags but only know where the text starts and ends. Could I use a tag such as <b> to do this (with css stylin)? Or is it a really bad idea?

Do you have any other suggestions?

Edit: I cannot easily change the HTML so validation is not useful. The HTML is user generated.

Comment: use an html validator (try http://validator.w3.org/ ) it will tell you that this case is invalid.

Comment: That isn't a bad idea. It's the worst idea :D There are no ways to get everything inside one unique div? In your expample, something like <div>aaaa<div class="HIDEME"><div>bbbb</div></div>ccccc</div> ?

Comment: its not a good idea to use any div inside a "b" or "span". `<div> <b>bbbbb</b> </div>` is the right way to do that

Comment: but for making the tag hidden "span" is better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't allowed. It is just the browser trying to perform error recovery.

Elements must be arranged in a tree structure. Each element has a single parent element (root node excepted).

Given the above input, Chrome will generate this:

```
<div> aaaaaaaa <b></b></div><b>
<div> bbbbbbbb </div>
</b><div><b> </b> ccccccccc </div>
```

You should not depend on this type of error recovery. Always remember to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Using malformed HTML is a bad idea, as different browsers treat such "errors" differently. But you can always nest content in a parent div element, which you can hide/show.

Like this:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">
  <div>First hidden sentence</div>
  <div>Second hidden sentence</div>
</div>
```